# WPF AppBar autohide implementation

Tags: wpf, animation, appbar

I'm a beginner learning WPF, and need to create an Application Bar that launches applications. I need it to auto hide, but I'm struggling with this. I implemented the docking aspect fine, and registered it as an autohide toolbar with windows, but am unsure how to go about actually implementing the autohide functionality. Currently, my window using a storyboard event to "hide" by changing to opacity to 0, but then the bar will still be 'on top' and block all of the other applications, so this doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting your opacity, set the visibility to collapsed at the end.  Once the element is transparent, the collapsed status will make it unable to be hit by mouse.  Do the opposite (Visibility set to Visible, then change opacity or whatever) on the opening animation.

Comment: CodeWarrior, Thanks for responding. If I do that, then how do I detect that the mouse is near the edge to begin the opening animation at all?

Comment: I would do this thusly assuming this is going to be docked at say the bottom:  Create a grid with at least two rows.  The bottom row should be say 5 px height, the top row should be Auto height.  Place the meat and potatoes of the UI in the top row filling it.  In the animation, fade the UI in the top row and then collapse it leaving the bottom row visible.  Then you will always have an area visible and hittable that can fire events (like IsMouseOver, etc).