# Is it possible to implement the windows 8 Charm Bar Menu in a desktop app?

Tags: windows, desktop-application

Is it possible to implement the windows 8 Charm Bar Menu in a desktop app?

[image]

The program would be always running but "hidden" till the mouse goes over it. At this moment it would appear.

I was thinking in something like WPF but im not sure if this can be done with it.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, if it was done for windows 8 it is possible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that? An app for windows < 8 to imitate the windows 8 charm bar?

Comment: It will be a independent(standalone?) program for windows vista and 7.. not w8.

Comment: The mechanism for this has been around since Windows 95: It's call an [auto-hide appbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc144177#autohide_application_desktop_toolbars). [Here's an example in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6427895) as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this I would program a [notification window](http://www.canofcode.co.uk/software/wpf-notification-popup/) and [monitor the mouse position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx). If the mouse is at the right side of the desktop you can show the notification window.

With a little work you can change the look and feel of the notification window to look like the charm bar and add some effects :-)

In conclusion it should be possible.